# Is there a converse to the Brauer–Nesbitt theorem?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, arithmetic-geometry, modules, characters, traces

$\DeclareMathOperator\Tr{Tr}$Say that we have an algebra $R$ over $\mathbb{C}$. If, for two finitely generated (edit: and semisimple) $R$-modules $M, N$ we know that $\Tr_M(r)=\Tr_N(r)$ for all $r\in R$, where we consider $r$ as the linear endomorphism of the corresponding module, then we know that $M\cong N$ by the Brauer–Nesbitt theorem.

My question is, assuming that we have specific values for traces (some homomorphism $g: R \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $g(rr')=g(r'r)$ for every $r, r'\in R$), do we know that there exists some module $M$ with $Tr_M(r)=g(r)$ for every $r$? If not, can we somehow efficiently describe the functions that can appear as traces?

Comment: Your statement of the Brauer--Nesbitt theorem is incorrect: you need $M$ and $N$ to be semisimple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not always — e.g. $g(1)$ should be an integer. The desired description is given in

*Helling, H.*, [**Eine Kennzeichnung von Charakteren auf Gruppen und assoziativen Algebren**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00927877408548718), Commun. Algebra 1, 491-501 (1974). [ZBL0288.16019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0288.16019).

---

**Edit as requested:** To a linear $g:R\to\mathbf C$ with $g(rs)=g(sr)$ Helling attaches $g_n:R^n\to\mathbf C$ by
$$
g_n(r_1,\dots,r_n)= \sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak S_n}(-1)^\sigma\prod_{(i_1,\dots,i_l):\text{ cycle of }\sigma}g(r_{i_1}\!\cdots r_{i_l})
$$
and proves (Satz p. 496): $g$ is a character iff $g_n=0$ for some integer $n$.

Comment: Is there an English version? I do not know German... Or any reference that contains the results of this paper in English? Sorry to be picky and thanks for the answer in any case!

Comment: The Zentralblatt link gives more recent papers quoting this one.

Comment: I checked them but still everybody just references the paper, nobody explains the actual result (they are all of the type "this problem has been studied there") Could you possibly elaborate a little on your answer on what the results of the paper are?

Comment: In arithmetic geometry, this question has been studied for a while under the name of "pseudo-representation" (apparently introduced by Wiles in that context in "On ordinary λ-adic representations associated to modular forms", Invent. Math 94 (1988), 529-573).  Searching for this gives many results, e.g, http://www.math.harvard.edu/~kisin/notes/notes2.pdf has some references to proofs by Taylor and by Rouquier of this result. (Interestingly, the paper of Helling is not mentioned in either Wiles's or Taylor's, so they must have re-discovered the result).

Comment: Thank you both a lot, these results are exactly what I needed!